Laravel Pagination Links Function Are Not Working Problem
I'm getting this error from 2 days. I have almost 1400 users data in my databse and want to show data on my website in pagination but after written my controller code :-
public function fetchData()
{
    $user = AddUser::paginate(25);
    return view('home', compact('user'));
}

whem I use the $user->links function,facing this error :- Call to undefined method App\Models\AddUser::links()
blade file code :-
<div class="w-[100%] overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="w-[100%] text-center mt-3 shadow-xl shadow-white">
        <thead class="bg-gray-950 uppercase">
            <tr>
                <th class="py-3 ">#</th>
                <th class="">First Name</th>
                <th class="">Last Name</th>
                <th class="">Email</th>
                <th class="">Action</th>
                <th class="">Action</th>
                <th class="">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="bg-gray-900">
            @foreach ($user as $users)
                <tr class="border-b-2 border-blue-600">
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">{{ $users->fname }}</td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">{{ $users->lname }}</td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">{{ $users->email }}</td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">
                        <a href=" {{ route('view', $users->id) }}"
                            class="bg-blue-600 py-1 rounded-sm hover:bg-blue-900 duration-300 px-3">View</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">
                        <a href="{{ route('delete', $users->id) }}"
                            class="bg-yellow-500 py-1 rounded-sm hover:bg-yellow-900 duration-300 px-3">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="py-3 px-5">
                        <a href="{{ route('update', $users->id) }}"
                            class="bg-red-600 py-1 rounded-sm hover:bg-red-900 duration-300 px-3">Update</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach


        </tbody>

    </table>

    {{ $users->links() }} // here is the error
</div>

I'm using larvavel 11 latest version
I don't have any idea what's the problem.

$users is a singular model, $user is your collection that has the pagination links. You might want to switch those variable names, as it's causing obvious confusion.

yes, I did. but not working

Make sure you're calling ->links() on the collection, not the individual model that you're using inside of your loop. If it still doesn't work, [edit] the post with your updated code and the current error message.

Yep, in your controller, rename the variable from $user to $users

Have you added a Paginator in AppServiceProvider?
